Shoe pairs differing by at most 1
Question: You work at a shoe factory, and you’re working on creating boxes with pairs of shoes. Currently in front of you, imagine there are 3 pairs of shoes (for a total of 6 individual shoes) with the following sizes: 2 size 4s, 2 size 5s, 2 size 6s.  The factory defines an “acceptable” pair as 2 shoes that differ in size by a maximum of 1 size — so a shoe with size 5 and a shoe with size 6 would count as an “acceptable” pair. If you close your eyes, and randomly pick 3 pairs of shoes, without replacement, what is the probability that you end up drawing 3 acceptable pairs?
The correct answer to this question is 1/3, but I don't understand why my method is wrong:
Method:

I just listed out all possible outcomes (note that it doesn't matter about the order of the pairs or the elements within the pairs):
(4 4), (5 5), (6 6)
(4 5), (4 5), (6 6)
(5 6), (5 6), (4 4)
(4 6), (4 6), (5 5)
(4 6), (4 5), (5 6)
So the probability of getting 3 acceptable pairs is 3/5

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Since these are shoes rather than socks, do you pick a left shoe and a right shoe each time?

Presumably you mean that an acceptable pair would be $(4L, 5R)$ and such, yes?  Hard to imagine that $(4L, 5L)$ would work.  Accordingly, your labeling system isn't good enough, as you need to distinguish parity.

I get $\frac 15$ under my assumption.  I have written the computation below.

Your method only refers to one pair. Not three pairs.  BTW, I'd personally interpret the sentence "The factory defines an “acceptable” pair as 2 shoes that differ in size by a maximum of 1 size " and "If you close your eyes, and randomly pick 3 pairs of shoes" as meaning handednes does NOT matter (how can you randomly pick a pair of left-right shoes if the shoes aren't already ordered in pairs?) and in defining an "acceptable" pair it needs to be stated handedness matters.  (Although I agree that the text is probably intended handedness, I just personally think the book is badly worded.)

Assuming "handedness" matters, so $(4L,5R)$ is acceptable but $(4L, 5L)$ isn't (using what I trust is obvious notation):
The acceptable pairs are then $$(4L,4R), (4L, 5R), (4R, 5L), (5L, 5R), (5L, 6R), (5R, 6L), (6L, 6R)$$
Here, the order within a pair is irrelevant.  Thus $(4L,4R)$ is the same choice as $(4R,4L)$.
There are, of course, $\binom 62=15$ equally probable selections for the first pair (including both acceptable and unacceptable choices).
If, say, you chose $(5L,6R)$ initially then you are left with $\{4L,4R,5R,6L\}$  So there is a unique way to form two acceptable pairs out of what is left.  As there are $\binom 42=6$ ways to choose one pair and there are two good options, the probability that the next two selections are also acceptable is $\frac 26=\frac 13$.
This holds for all of the mixed sizes and for the case in which you chose $(5L,5R)$ initially.  Thus this analysis covers $5$ of the $7$ acceptable first selections.
If you chose $(4L,4R)$ or $(6L,6R)$ initially then it is different.  If, say, you chose $(4L,4R)$ then what's left is $\{5L,5R,6L,6R\}$ and now whichever one you choose has two good "mates", making the probabiltiy $\frac 23$ in this case.  (example:  if the first choice was $5L$ then the second could be $5R$ or $6R$ and either way the remaining pair is acceptable).
Combining all this, the answer is $$\frac 5{15}\times \frac 13+\frac 2{15}\times \frac 23=\frac 9{45}=\boxed {\frac 15}$$

The answer $1/3$ is correct when boots of the same size are identical. Indeed, the formulation of the problem does not mention that boots can be left and right. The probabilities of selecting two acceptable pairs of shoes from four given sizes are as follows:
$$
P(4,4,5,5) = 1,\qquad P(5,5,6,6) = 1,
$$
$$
P(4,5,6,6) = \frac14\frac13+\frac14\frac13+\frac12\frac13 = \frac13,\qquad P(4,4,5,6) = \frac13,
$$
$$
P(4,4,6,6) = \frac12\frac13+\frac12\frac13 = \frac13.
$$
When calculating $P(4,5,6,6)$, the terms that make up the probability correspond to the three following ways of choosing the first pair: (4,5) or (5,4) or (6,6), and when calculating $P(4,4,6,6)$ the terms correspond to the two ways of choosing the first pair: (4,4) or (6,6). When there are six shoes, you will choose size 4 with probability $\frac13$. After that, you must choose size 4 (probability $\frac15$) or size 5 (probability $\frac25$). Therefore, the probability of choosing the first shoe of size 4 (or 6) and all pairs being acceptable is
$$
P_4 = \frac13\left(\frac15P(5,5,6,6)+\frac25P(4,5,6,6)\right) = \frac19 = P_6
$$
If the first shoe you choose is size 5 (probability $\frac13$), then you can then choose size 5 (probability $\frac15$) or size 4 (probability $\frac25$) or size 6 (probability $\frac25$). And the probability of choosing size 5 first and having all pairs acceptable is
$$
P_5 = \frac13\left(\frac15P(4,4,6,6)+\frac25P(4,5,6,6)+\frac25P(4,4,5,6)\right) = \frac19.
$$
Finally, the desired probability
$$
P_4+P_5+P_6 = \frac13
$$

Shoes (as opposed to socks) always have a distinct left-right. Also pairs of shoes are being chosen, not shoe by shoe according to the wording.
I name the truly matched pairs (in increasing size) as $Aa, Bb$, and $Cc$, then it is easy to see that there are just three successful patterns, viz.
$Aa-Bb-Cc,\;Ab-aB-Cc, \; Aa-Bc-bC$, each with $6$ permutations  against $\binom62\binom42\binom22= 90$ possible pairings
Thus P(all three pairs "matched") $=\frac{18}{90}=\frac15$
